# Why is 8 so special?

Tags: number-systems, octonions

I have been reading about multi-dimensional numbers, and found out that it's been proven that the Octonions are the composition algebra of the largest dimension. I was wondering why, despite having infinitely many different dimensions of numbers, the only composition algebras are of 1, 2, 4, and 8 dimensions. What's so special about 8?

Comment: See [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529) [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32100) [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38604).

Comment: @J. M.: you are the link-master! Also, in light of "those three questions", would this be a duplicate topic?

Comment: @Chaz: I'm on the fence, and will thus let other people vote on it.

Comment: @J.M., I have to agree with The Chaz. I usually have a hard time searching for question here and I end up using Google with `site:math.stackexchange.com`. Any tips on searching? The default OR in searches here is not convenient and I don't think it searches comments.

Comment: @lhf: I did use Google (the built-in search is remarkably unhelpful); here the magic search-words are "quaternion" and "Frobenius". (Yes, Google can parse comments. Whodathunkit, eh?) Also, I happen to remember those three well...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tw8w4YPp4zM kinda both entertaining and informative

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be interested in Hurwitz's proof of his [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28normed_division_algebras%29) (which is not as strong as Wikipedia's statement). Here is the [original German](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/Hurwitz%20Ueber%20die%20Komposition%20der%20quadratischen%20Formen.pdf) and an [English translation](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/Compositions%20of%20quadratic%20forms%20after%20Hurwitz.pdf). The maximal $n$ turns out to be the solution of $2^{n-2} = n^2$.

Answer (score -1):

Your information is wrong: tessarines of any $2^n$ dimension (for instance, 16-dimensional tessarines) is a commutative, associative, composition algebra.