# What constitutes 2-dimensional similarity?

Tags: complex-numbers, plane-geometry

In a [discussion regarding the relation between 2D-vectors and complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3427920) numbers Jagerber48  states:

> This isn't to say there aren't important similarities between
> the two spaces (they are both 2-dimensional, for example)
> that are worth keeping in mind to help get intuition to
> solve various problems.

Does the statement "they are both 2-dimensional" have some mathematical depth or is it only illustrative? The mathematical [Wikipedia article on the lookup word 2-dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_space) does not add much more than also point to some kind of similarity between a 2D-plane and the complex plane. If it's **not** only illustrative; what's required to assert they are both 2-dimensional and hence "similar" in that respect, although different in other aspects?

Answer (score 1):

The complex plane is not just "similar" to a two-dimensional vector space. It **is** a two-dimensional vector space (over the real numbers). But in addition to this vector space structure it has more parts to it.

Most importantly, there is a certain notion of a product between two complex numbers that yields a new complex number. This structure goes beyond what vector spaces do and it is what makes the complex numbers what they are.

That doesn't stop the complex numbers from being a vector space. And it really shouldn't stop you from visualising the complex numbers in the plane. But it means there is more to them than just addition and length scaling.

Comment: Ok, I understand your the principle of your answer - especially the 2D similarity - but still find the concept a bit ambigous. Especially in this regard: "This structure goes beyond what vector spaces do" + "That doesn't stop the complex numbers from being a vector space", if the Complex Numbers go beyond what vector spaces do but still is a vector space, isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: @Oortone Squares go beyond what rectangles do. They have more structure imposed on them. They are still rectangles.