# Is there a reasonable limit to how far you can generalise complex numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, real-numbers, quaternions, octonions

Real numbers satisfy a(bc) = (ab)c as well as ab = ba. They are also comparable.

Generalising to complex numbers, everything stays the same, except the numbers lose their comparibility.

Generalising to quaternions, the ab = ba no longer holds

Generalising to octonions, a(bc) = (ab)c no longer holds.

My question is, can you keep generalising indefinitely, and is there ever a point where the resulting number system has lost so many useful relations/identities that it just becomes a useless mush? (As a speculative example, perhaps it may become so generalised that something as simple as "a + b" becomes meaningless or uncomputable)

Comment: This type of question has been asked many times on this site. See for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86434/what-lies-beyond-the-sedenions), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586998/how-many-super-imaginary-numbers-are-there/2587002#2587002), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123907/is-there-is-a-number-system-which-is-extension-of-complex-number-system) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38604/the-largest-number-system).

Comment: And if it weren't a duplicate, it would be opinion-based (because 'reasonable' is subjective.)

Comment: You definitely can have a hypercomplex number system which is associative and commutative of any dimension you want. But you will get zero divisors (which is not that much bad though). The simplest example is $\mathbb{R}^n$, each number being represented by sets of $n$ reals like $(a,b,c,d,e)$. with element-wise addition and multiplication. In such system $(a,a,a,a,a)$ would be equal to real number $a$. And you will have zero divisors (any set with a zero but not all zeros).

Answer (score 4):

I am no expert on this topic, but this hierarchy is generated by the [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction). When you apply it to the octonions to make the *sedenions*, you lose **alternativity**, which is a weaker form of associativity: it requires $x(xy) = (xx)y$ and $y(xx) = (yx)x$. You also gain zero-divisors. At this stage, you can keep going (as many times as you want, actually), but there's almost no nice properties left.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on @It'sNotALie's discussion of the Cayley–Dickson_construction, it can be used to double the dimension of an any algebraic structure satisfying certain conditions; these are sometimes called algebras with involutions. They have commutative and associative addition with identity $0$, multiplication that's power-associative (i.e. $x$ commutes with $xx$) and left- and right-distributive over addition with identity $1$, and an involution ${}^\ast$ with $(x+y)^\ast=x^\ast+y^\ast,\,(xy)^\ast=y^\ast x^\ast$. We can prove the following:

- The new algebra satisfies the same axioms;
- The new one contains elements satisfying $x^\ast\ne x$, i.e. is not self-conjugate;
- The new one commutes iff the old one was self-conjugate, associates iff the old one commmuted, and alternates iff the old one associated.

With this, we can explain why properties are shedded as they are by each of $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb H$ (quaternions), $\Bbb O$ (octonions), $\Bbb S$ (sedenions, which also introduces zero divisors, i.e. solutions to $xy=0,\,x\ne0,\,y\ne0$; this costs us a norm). Beyond $\Bbb S$, we preserve all properties so far discussed that survive to $\Bbb S$.

There are [other options](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586998/how-many-super-imaginary-numbers-are-there/2587002#2587002) where we don't just use square roots of $-1$ to double the dimension over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the further details on this, really interesting to read!