# What is the term for when a set 'inherits' its algebraic properties from another?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For example, the rules for arithmetic on complex numbers are a direct result of complex numbers being defined as pairs of real numbers. Thus, the algebraic properties of the reals also apply to the complex numbers. Is there a term for this?

Comment: I understand it has additional properties to C, but I'm wondering how to describe the process by which one set 'inherits' properties from a subset it's built on.

Comment: If you are familiar with rings, in particular basic properties of polynomial rings and quotient rings, then you can find an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242).  That assumes you construct it *efficiently* using general ring constructions (vs. brute-force verifying all the ring laws, as some authors do).

Comment: My original example - and I'm not sure if it's relevant to the idea I'm trying to get at - is that $\alpha+\beta = \beta + \alpha$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ as a direct result of the definition of a complex number as an ordered pair of reals. Thus, addition is commutative in $\mathbb{C}$ because it is commutative in $\mathbb{R}$. Is there some sort of term for this to describe how a set's algebraic structure is built on that of a subset?

Comment: In your prior comment it seems you are viewing $\Bbb C$ as an [*algebra* over the field $\Bbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field). It is difficult to know how to answer your question without knowing if you are familiar with these basic  algebraic structures (rings, modules, algebras, and their quotients), Please clarify that.

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close. This question is indeed a little vague, but I think this is a situation where it's impossible to ask a much clearer version of the question without already knowing how to answer it.

Comment: I agree with @NoahSchweber that it is a worthwhile Question, despite being asked at a disadvantage of not knowing the best terminology.  The additive properties of $\mathbb R$ go easily over into the construction of $\mathbb C$, but the multiplicative properties not so easily.  You might be interested in what happens when we try to [repeat this construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836977/is-there-a-reasonable-limit-to-how-far-you-can-generalise-complex-numbers), getting the quaternions, the octonions, the sedonians... and then things run dry, sort of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great question! There's a lot of material here, and no snappy answer; broadly speaking, you're running into themes from **universal algebra**, **category theory**, and **model theory** (which is not to say that these themes are exclusive to those areas of course).

To set the stage, I want to mention three separate facts:

1. The commutativity and associativity of *addition* of complex numbers does indeed "come immediately" from the commutativity and associativity of addition of real numbers.
2. Meanwhile, the commutativity and associativity of *multiplication* of complex numbers does not follow quite so easily, and this isn't too surprising given that the definition of complex multiplication is more intricate than the definition of complex addition.

   - To be a bit more explicit: if we think of $a+bi$ as the ordered pair $(a,b)$, "easy" multiplication would be $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$, but "complex" (hehe) multiplication is $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$.
3. And there are basic algebraic properties which do not in fact lift from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ at all. For example, the rule $$\forall x,y(x^2+y^2=0\implies x=y=0)$$ is true in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but false in $\mathbb{C}$. Put another way, we can do division in the complex numbers but not in the "square real numbers."

So there are real distinctions to be made.

---

### Products preserve equations (and more!)

Let's start by focusing on point $1$ - the tameness of $\mathbb{C}$-addition as an immediate consequence of the tameness of $\mathbb{R}$-addition. This is actually (relatively) easy to explain:

There is a very general way of combining two *(or more but let's ignore that for now)* "algebraic structures of the same type," such as two sets equipped with a binary operation: the **direct product**. In the specific case of sets equipped with a single binary operation, this is defined as follows: given "starting structures" $(A_1;*_1), (A_2;*_2)$, the product structure $$(A_1;*_1)\times (A_2;*_2)$$ is just $(A_1\times A_2; \star),$ where $\star$ is defined componentwise as $(a_1,a_2)\star (b_1,b_2)=(a_1*_1b_1, a_2*_2b_2)$.

Now why is this relevant? Well, if we look just at the additive structure in each case, we get $$(\mathbb{R};+)^2\cong(\mathbb{C};+).$$ So the way complex addition is built from real addition really is such a "one-step" process.

> **WARNING**: I am **not** saying that "$\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{C}$"! That would be horribly misleading - that notation suggests that I'm referring to both addition and multiplication, and it is *not* true that $(\mathbb{R};+_\mathbb{R},\times_\mathbb{R})^2\cong(\mathbb{C};+_\mathbb{C},\times_\mathbb{C})$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have $(1,0)\times (0,1)=(0,0)$, but in $\mathbb{C}$ we can never multiply two nonzero things to get zero.

It turns out that there is a very general result that applies in such a situation:

> $Th_{eq}(\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B})=Th_{eq}(\mathcal{A})\cap Th_{eq}(\mathcal{B})$.

*(In fact this holds for products of infinitely many structures as well, but meh.)* Here $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are "algebraic structures of the same type" - e.g. sets equipped with a single binary operation, in our case - $\times$ is the direct product, and $Th_{eq}(\mathcal{X})$ is the **equational theory** of $\mathcal{X}$; that is, the set of all expressions of the form $$\forall x_1,...,x_n[t(x_1,...,x_n)=s(x_1,...,x_n)]$$ for terms $t,s$ in the language of $\mathcal{X}$ which are true in $\mathcal{X}$ for any assignment of values to variables. That's a bit of a mouthful, but all it means is that the equational theory contains things like **commutativity** (= "$\forall x_1,x_2[x_1*x_2=x_2*x_1]$") and **associativity** (= "$\forall x_1,x_2,x_3[x_1*(x_2*x_3)=(x_1*x_2)*x_3]$").

And this is just the start of the story. Here are a couple more points:

- Equational truth is preserved by taking **substructures** and **quotients** as well *(although we may in each case gain new equations to boot - a quotient of a nonabelian group might be abelian, for example)*. And in a precise sense (the HSP theorem - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4127012/part-of-birkhoffs-hsp-theorem-for-varieties-of-groups/4127089#4127089)) this is the whole story.
- Meanwhile, products preserve more than just equations - they also preserve *implications between* equations. If "$s=t\implies u=v$" is true in both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, then it will also be true in $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}$. A relevant term here is "Horn clause" (and you may be interested in the results mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416648/how-hard-is-it-to-say-not-exactly-p-with-a-horn-sentence)).

---

### Building "full" $\mathbb{C}$ from "full" $\mathbb{R}$

OK, now what happens when we fold multiplication into the mix?

Right off the bat things are more complicated. Let's compare the commutativity proofs for complex **addition** and complex **multiplication**. The proof of commutativity of addition is more-or-less just $$(a,b)+_\mathbb{C}(c,d)=(a+_\mathbb{R}c, b+_\mathbb{R}d)=(c+_\mathbb{R}a, d+_\mathbb{R}b)=(c,d)+_\mathbb{C}(b,a).$$ We literally just apply $+_\mathbb{R}$-commutativity twice in the obvious ways. The proof of commutativity of multiplication, however, is a bit more involved: it goes as $$(a,b)\times_\mathbb{C}(c,d)=((a\times_\mathbb{R}c)-_\mathbb{R}(b\times_\mathbb{R}d), (a\times_\mathbb{R}d)+_\mathbb{R}(b\times_\mathbb{R}c))=((c\times_\mathbb{R}a)-_\mathbb{R}(d\times_\mathbb{R}b), (c\times_\mathbb{R}b)+_\mathbb{R}(d\times_\mathbb{R}a))=(c,d)\times_\mathbb{C}(a,b).$$ We had to use the commutativity of *addition* along the way (look carefully)! And subtraction - a very *non*-commutative operation - made an appearance along the way. Meanwhile, [more complicated iterations of the basic idea of building $\mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{R}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) do indeed fail to be multiplicatively commutative. Finally (and this was point (3) above but let's recall it anyways since it's been a while), since the multiplicative identity has square roots in $\mathbb{C}$ but not $\mathbb{R}$ it's certainly not true that *all* basic facts about multiplication lift from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

So there is a genuine issue here. It turns out that we can build $(\mathbb{C};+,\times)$ from $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ in an equation-preserving way, but it's a bit tricky:

- We start by forming the direct product of **infinitely many** copies of $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$. Concretely, an element of this really big algebra is an infinite sequence $(r_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers, and we add and multiply componentwise. (Note that $(0,0,0,...)$ is the additive identity and $(1,1,1,...)$ is the multiplicative identity.) Per above remarks, this giant structure - call it "$\mathcal{S}$" - has the same equational theory as the reals.
- Now we carve out a particular "substructure" - let $\mathcal{X}$ be the set of all sequences of real numbers that you can build via (componentwise) addition and multiplication from the constant sequences and the sequence $\mathfrak{x}=(1,2,3,...)$.
- With some work, you can show that this $\mathcal{X}$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[X]$; the isomorphism I have in mind is the one generated by sending each constant sequence $(r,r,r,r,...)$ to the constant polynomial $r$, and sending $\mathfrak{x}$ to the monomial $X$. Now it's well-known that $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $\mathbb{R}[X]$, so in fact we have that $\mathbb{C}$ is (isomorphic to) a quotient of a substructure of a power of $\mathbb{R}$ - so, by the above remarks, every equation true in $\mathbb{R}$ is true in $\mathbb{C}$ as well. And since $\mathbb{R}$ is (isomorphic to) a substructure of $\mathbb{C}$, the converse holds too - their equational theories coincide!

*Admittedly, we could sidestep universal algebra entirely and simply do the following. Suppose "$s(\overline{x})=t(\overline{x})$" is an equation true in $\mathbb{R}$. This means (in $\mathbb{C}$) that $s-t$ is a multivariate polynomial vanishing on all real inputs, and we can show via elementary means that this means $s-t$ is identically zero. This avoids the more abstract approach above, but arguably loses some explanatory power.*