# Do rings in general pass on their properties to their field of fractions? If not, which properties are passed on and which not?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For instance we know that $\mathrm{Frac}(\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Q}$ or that $\mathrm{Frac}(2\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Q}$ and we know that $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

These are fields, but do they also pass on their properties? $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn’t have an inverse for multiplication, but everything else is the same as $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ **isn't** a field, and the field of fractions of a field $F$ is just $F$ itself. Do you mean to refer to **rings**?

Comment: The passing on of properties is that whenever you have a nontrivial ring homomorphism from that ring to a field, there is a unique corresponding field homomorphism from the field of fractions to that field …

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes ! Sorry

Answer (score 1):

*This answer unfortunately gets fairly technical fairly quickly; I've tried to keep it readable nonetheless, but please let me know if you have ideas for improvements. Also, per the comments I'm assuming that "field" is a typo for "ring."*

---

Every **equational** sentence is preserved by the field-of-fractions construction. An equational sentence is an expression of the form $$\forall a_1,...,a_n (t(a_1,...,a_n)=s(a_1,...,a_n))$$ for terms $t,s$ in the relevant language. In the context of rings, "terms" are just polynomials - so for example the property of being a [*Boolean ring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) is expressible by an equational sentence, namely $\forall a(a*a=a)$. Equational expressions are quite limited, but there's still a lot of complexity there. The big theorem I'll use is the following:

> $(*)\quad$ Suppose $\mathbb{A}$ is a quotient of a substructure of a (possibly infinitary) direct power of $\mathbb{B}$. Then every equational sentence true in $\mathbb{B}$ is true in $\mathbb{A}$ as well. And if $\mathbb{B}$ is (isomorphic to) a substructure of $\mathbb{A}$ as well, then the converse holds and $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$ satisfy exactly the same equational sentences.

This is a special case of the easy direction of Birkhoff's HSP theorem *(see [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Birkhoff%27s_theorem), or [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4127089/28111) if you're interested in an outline of the harder direction in the special case of groups)*, which basically showed that the operations of taking products, substructures, and homomorphic images (also called quotients) are the precise "basic ingredients" needed for equational-sentence-preserving constructions. I'll leave the proof of $(*)$ as an exercise for now; it's not especially hard, but it is somewhat tedious.

Let's suppose $R$ is an **integral domain**, that is, a commutative ring (with unity) and no zero divisors (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)) for why that is a reasonable restriction). Its field of fractions $F_R$ can be defined as follows:

- First we form the multivariable polynomial ring $R[\{x_r: r\in R\setminus\{0\}\}]$. I'll abbreviate that set of variables by "$X$" for simplicity.
- Next, we mod out by the relations $x_rr=1$ for each $r\in R\setminus\{0\}$.

OK, so this gives two separate constructions: $R\leadsto R[X]$ ("adjoin lots of indeterminates") and $R[X]\leadsto F_R$ ("mod out by a messy ideal"). The latter is simply a surjective homomorphism and so preserves equations by $(*)$. But how do we adjoin indeterminates? Even figuring out how to adjoin a *single* indeterminate using just power, substructure, and quotient constructions is not obvious, but it can be done. To keep things concrete, let's think about the specific case of $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the really big ring $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ (I'm being a bit sloppy with notation here in the interest of readability) consisting of all infinite sequences of integers $(z_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with componentwise addition and multiplication. There's an obvious way to see $\mathbb{Z}$ "sitting inside" $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$, namely by considering the map $$\eta:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\infty: z\mapsto (z,z,z,z,...).$$ On the other hand, we also have wacky things like the *identity sequence* $$\iota=(1,2,3,4,...)$$ (I'm starting indexing from $1$ instead of $0$ here). The point is that such "wacky" elements of $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ **behave like indeterminates** in the sense that (for example) if we write "$\langle U\rangle_W$" for the subring of $W$ generated by $U$ there is an isomorphism $$\mathbb{Z}[x]\cong \langle ran(\eta)\cup\{\iota\}\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}^\infty}.$$ This tells us that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ - up to isomorphism, anyways - is indeed a subring of a power of $\mathbb{Z}$ and so satisfies all the equational sentences that $\mathbb{Z}$ itself does. Of course we're not done - we've only figured out how to adjoin a *single* indeterminate to the *specific* ring $\mathbb{Z}$ - but the broader result we need is no harder to get.

---

Incidentally, this same argument gives as a special case that the fields $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ have the same equational theory; see the latter part of [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435772/what-is-the-term-for-when-a-set-inherits-its-algebraic-properties-from-another/4435954#4435954) for more on this. Incidentally, this specific fact can also be proved using complex analysis (think about what happens if a polynomial vanishes on all real inputs).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez By $R$ do you mean $\mathbb{R}$? If so, the answer is *negative*: every nonzero $n$-ary polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ has range $\supsetneq\{0\}$ as a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so only the equations which hold as a consequence of the ring axioms do. Which I guess makes a lot of what I wrote here/elsewhere redundant, but meh.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  I downvoted accidentally Dec 21 and didn't notice until I had investigated a rep change of +9 just now.  If you make any edit, I'm happy to rescind my downvote.  (Am I able to edit just so that I can change my vote?)